# Shall I use JSONB for integers based array?

Tags: postgresql

I need to store a list of ids in array per each row.
I thought to use JSONB, then store it as : `{ids: [1, 2, 3, 4]}`.
Then, I found `Array` type, that I can use to store ids directly into.
The question is, what is the recommended data type for my case?

Comment: Arrays are non-standard and a breach of the relational model. As @CraigRinger points out, it's well nigh impossible to join arrays to anything. IMHO, arrays in RDBMS's are the work of the devil :-)

Comment: Joining on arrays isn't *too* bad in Pg. But it's not particularly efficient or easy to optimise, you can't use FKs, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise, the recommended storage is *always* normalised.

Store the integers in a separate table of `(other_row_id, the_integer)` and join on them.

If you *must* use arrays, use PostgreSQL's native arrays `ARRAY[1,2,3]`.

Storing them as `jsonb` is a spectacularly inefficient and clumsy way to do it with essentially no advantages.

Comment: What do you mean by the recommended storage is always normalised?

Comment: @MohammadAL-Raoosh Presumably a reference to [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), a method of exploiting the functionality of the RDBMS to achieve increased efficiency

Comment: @MTCoster I'd say efficiency is rather a side-effect of normalisation than its aim: modern DBMSes are optimised for normalised data *because* normalisation was seen as a good thing. The primary driving force for the invention of normalisation was consistency and integrity.

Comment: @IMSoP Good point! Apparently I've got the whole thing backwards in my head somehow